# Refreshing a kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo UI grid , with data and background-color as green for cell .

Now when I do

```
$(grid).data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

the color is lost .How do I preserve the color also?

Comment: This likely depends on the technique you are using to make the cell green in the first place.  I would need to see the template or the dataBound event you are using and some sample data to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```